# How to get area inside a contour?

Tags: python, contour, area

I have a single contour that I'd like to find the area of (image at end of post- contour is the clue line, and is described by the blue set of points). I have tried to use alphashape for this (see below), but it does not work well enough for my purposes (alphashape approximation of contour in green on the image). Are there other methods that I can use to get the area inside this contour?

Thanks!

Here's my code so far. points is a list of all the single contours that I want to do this to.

```
for cnum in np.arange(0,(len(points))): 
    cpoints_nan=points[cnum]
    cpoints=[]
    for i in np.arange(0, len(cpoints_nan)): #Get rid of nan pairs 
        if np.isnan(cpoints_nan[i][0]): #If current pair of points is [nan, nan]
            continue
        else: #If current pair of points is not nan, add to cpoints
            cpoints.append([cpoints_nan[i][0][np.logical_not(np.isnan(cpoints_nan[i][0]))][0], cpoints_nan[i][1][np.logical_not(np.isnan(cpoints_nan[i][1]))][0]])
    if len(cpoints)>3: #Need more than two points to use alphashape. Greater than 3 because for closed "loops" the last point is the first and so this will still just form a line rather than a polygon
        alpha=alphashape.optimizealpha(cpoints)
        hull = alphashape.alphashape(cpoints, alpha)
        contour_areas.append(hull.area) #Get area inside contour
```

EDIT: Many of the contours I'm looking at are self-intersecting, so this is an additional layer of complexity

Contour image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBnmv.png

Comment: use the shoelance formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula... or convert the contour points into a shapely polygon, which has an area attribute

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the points are in the correct order, that the line doesn't self-intersect and that the line forms a complete shape (after points[-1] comes point[1]) you can compute the are by summing the individual partial signed areas:

```
# p = cpoints
area = 0
for i in range(len(p) -1):
  area += (p[i][0] - p[i+1][0]) * (p[i][1] + p[i+1][1]) / 2
area += (p[i][0] - p[-1][0]) * (p[i][1] + p[-1][1]) / 2
```

For each line segment you compute the area between it and the x axis. If the line goes to the left the area is added, if the line goes to the right the area is subtracted. This gives you the correct area because you add for the portion of the contour that faces up and subtract for the portion that faces down.

This is sensitive to the order of the points (they have to be in trigonometric sense to give a positive area). If your points go clockwise multiply by -1. If you don't care take the absolute value at the end.

This should give you a good result, but be careful of numeric instability if you have extreme values or a lot of points.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know about! Unfortunately, though, many of the contours that I have to deal with do self-intersect, and this is an aspect that I need to keep when finding the area given the nature of the problem I'm investigating. Are there any good ways to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: If you have self intersections, the algorithm above will count one part positive and one part negative so you get the difference between the two areas. If you know that you have simple situations like a single intersection you can try to find the intersecting segments and split the shape into 2, compute the areas for each and sum them up. If it's more complicated I would look for something else.